# Taking down multiple Azure Website Instances simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

Quote from the [Azure Web Jobs Documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment):

> **Persisted files**
>
> This is what you can view as your web site's files. They follow a
>   structure described here. They are rooted in d:\home, which can also
>   be found using the %HOME% environment variable.
>
> These files are persistent, meaning that you can rely on them staying
>   there until you do something to change them. Also, they are **shared
>   between all instances** of your site (when you scale it up to multiple
>   instances). Internally, the way this works is that they are stored in
>   Azure Storage instead of living on the local file system.

Does that imply that by dropping [app_offline.htm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912150/88513) into the site root folder should pretty much bring down all instances simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

*It doesn't bring them down exactly just redirects all traffic to that htm file.*

And it's easy to try for example using Visual Studio Online editor: 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/first-look-visual-studio

Or the DebugConsole:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/

Just add the file to wwwroot and browse to your site.