# Block website for a specific time slot(maintainence activity)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i block of page requests to the website , and make it unavailable (redirect to an error page) for a specific time slot?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912142/put-a-website-in-maintenance-mode

Answer (score 3):

You can place a file named `app_offline.htm` in the root directory of your ASP.NET website and `ASP.NET` will automatically route all traffic to this html page. In this file you can have any HTML code to show end user that maintenance is currently in process.

Other way of doing the same can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/219637/Put-the-website-in-Maintanance-Mode-Under-Construc)

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient info.But still you can use any of the methods. HTTHandlers in ASP.net Web forms Action Filters in ASP.net MVC. You can just check a flag set in Config file to determine whether to redirect or not if it needs to be configurable. Else you can check specific condition.